Display A Post At A URL without Redirecting
I want to have a single post show up for multiple URLs.  The post would be at "category/post-name/" and I want all URLs like "category/post-name/asdfa" to show the post, but keep the URL not redirect to the post.
So far, using the rewrite_rule and template stuff I can only get it to redirect to the post, not stay at the same URL and show the post.

Hi Sarah. Could you explain a little more about your issue? Reviewing https://xyproblem.info/ might help.
